# How do I solve an integral where the upper bounds could be 1 of 2 values?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, definite-integrals

While looking through the buffoon's needle problem solution I came across the this and was really confused.

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{m(\theta)} \frac{4}{d\pi }\,dx\,d\theta$$
where $m(\theta)$ is the minimum of ${\frac{l}{2}\sin\theta}$ and $\frac{t}{2}$

[Integral as seen on the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwSuo.png)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_needle_problem

Comment: Break it into two parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\theta = \theta'$ be the value where $\frac{t}{2} \sin \theta = \frac{l}{2}$, i.e. $\sin \theta' = \frac{l}{t}$. Then we can break the outer integral up into two parts:

$$\int_{\theta = 0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{x = 0}^{m(\theta)} \frac{4}{t \pi} dx d\theta = \int_{\theta = 0}^{\theta'} \int_{x=0}^{m(\theta)} \frac{4}{t \pi} dx d\theta + \int_{\theta = \theta'}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{x = 0}^{m(\theta)} \frac{4}{t \pi} dx d\theta$$

then notice that for the first integral, all of the values of $\theta$ we are integrating over are less than or equal to $\theta'$ so $\sin \theta \leq \sin \theta' = \frac{l}{t}$ and so $m(\theta) = \frac{t}{2} \sin \theta$, and similarly for the second integral all the values of $\theta$ are such that $m(\theta) = \frac{l}{2}$ and you can calculate the integrals as required.